# A function not Riemann integrable

Tags: measure-theory

There is a problem:

$f:\mathbb{R}\to\{1,-1\} $ defined by $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1 &\text{ if }x \in \mathbb{Q}\\-1 &\text{ if }x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$$
It's clear that it is not Riemann integrable but the question is "Is it Lebesgue Integrable ?"

I believe yes. I define a function 
$g (x)=-1 \text{ for all } x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then $f (x)=g (x)$ almost everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$ (as measure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $0$). $g$ is constant and hence Lebesgue Integrable. So $f$ is also Lebesgue integrable.
Am I correct?

Comment: A function $f$ is Lebesgue integrable over the real line if $\int_{\mathbb R} |f| d\mu < \infty$ ($\mu$ the Lebesgue measure). The functions $f$ and $g$ are not integrable since the integrals of each are infinite. They are integrable though over sets of finite measure though for the reason you give.

Comment: is -1 really Lebesgue integrable on $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @fonfonx no, its integral is infinite

Comment: @SubhajitSaha I think you are confusing the notions of measurability and integrability. You claim "$g$ is constant and hence Lebesgue integrable." That is not true. Constant functions are indeed $\it{measurable}$, but to determine if they are integrable you need to specify the set over which you are integrating them. In the case of constant functions, they can only be integrable on finite measure sets (unless of course the constant is $0$)

Comment: Yes;I get it.But is it necessary that the domain set of f has finite measure to get f as lebesgue integralable?

Comment: @pwerth yeah yeah I know :) it was a question to the OP, to make him realize his claim was wrong

Comment: @fonfox Yes;my claim was wrong

Comment: @SubhajitSaha No, but it is for nonzero constant functions. For example, the domain set can be $[1,\infty)$ and the function can be $1/x^{2}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. Note that a function is called Lebesgue integrable iff the Lebesgue integral of its positive part and that of its negative part are both finite.

Note that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f^{+} = \int_{\mathbb{Q}}1 = 0$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f^{-} = \int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}}1 =$ the measure of $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q} = +\infty$. So the Lebesgue integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f$ does not exist.